# Carousel Slide: İnsert Text and Link Adding for CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, slider, carousel, slideshow

I'm new to HTML and CSS. I just made a carousel slide using HTML and CSS. And I want to insert text in the corners of this slide. I couldn't do that because whatever I tried didn't work. I'm also trying to redirect to a different page when clicking on this slide.
I'am sorry my English btw. I hope I could explain what I mean.

CSS and HTML of my slide:

```css
.tech-slideshow {
  height: 190px;
  max-width: 2600px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.tech-slideshow > div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 2526px;
  background: url(https://resmim.net/cdn/2022/10/22/OybOx.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.tech-slideshow .mover-1 {
  animation: moveSlideshow 40s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes moveSlideshow {
  50% { 
    transform: translateX(-40%);  
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tech-slideshow">
  <div class="mover-1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, please specify what you mean by 'insert text in the corners of this slide'. To redirect to a different page you can wrap your slide into <a> html tag. It's ok since html5 to place block elements inside a link tag.

Comment: I just couldn't figure out where to add the link code. And how to place text over an slide? Can you show this on the code you are talking about as an example?

Comment: Fixed words should be written in the corners of the slide as in this picture. How do I do this? [link]https://resmim.net/i/O0K03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution with absolute positioning:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tech-slideshow {
  height: 190px;
  max-width: 2600px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.tech-slideshow__link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.mover-1 {
  width: 2526px;
  background: url(https://resmim.net/cdn/2022/10/22/OybOx.jpg);
  height: 100%;
  animation: moveSlideshow 40s linear infinite;
}

.mover-1-text {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0.5em 2em;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.mover-1-text1 {
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}

.mover-1-text2 {
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.mover-1-text3 {
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

@keyframes moveSlideshow {
  50% { 
    transform: translateX(-40%);  
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="tech-slideshow">
  <a href="#" class="tech-slideshow__link" target="_blank">      
     <div class="mover-1"></div>
     <p class="mover-1-text mover-1-text1">Text</p>
     <p class="mover-1-text mover-1-text2">Text</p>
     <p class="mover-1-text mover-1-text3">Text</p>
  </a>
</div>
```